# How to store a (partial or full) physical address in Swift

Tags: swift

How can I store a persons mailing address? Say two different users entered the information differently, so if one user were to say 123 Main Street, City, State-ABV, and another just entered City, State ABV.

I was thinking keep it simple and just do it as a String like this

```
func getAddy(houseNumber: Int, nameOfStreet streetName: String, nameOfCity cityNme: String, nameOfState stateAbrv: String) -> String {

    return "\(houseNumber) \(streetName) \(cityNme) \(stateAbrv)"
}
```

But I run into two problems. First the user might only enter partial data, and 2nd. Those street strings don't mean anything. It could say San Francisco or cheese. How can I give that meaning?

Is there an Address type?

Comment: Look at the address types used in the Contacts framework.

Comment: @rmaddy Ah, I was hesitant to use the Contacts framework because all the tutorials gave the impression I had to ask the user for permission with the goal of adding it to the address book. However, after reading the apple documentation and a quick test that is not the case. Thank you. If you want to put it as an answer I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CNPostalAddress` from the Contacts framework. It's a standalone class that doesn't actually require access to a user's contacts.